# Installing Windows 8 Consumer Preview returns an error

Tags: windows, vmware-player, windows-8-preview

I always get "A DVD driver your PC needs is missing." Then I click "Ok" and "No device drivers were found." pops up.

This occurs right after I select my language and keyboard. How do I fix it?

I'm installing the 32-bit consumer preview on VMware player on a 32-bit Windows 7.

Comment: Try to look for a guide to get a Windows 8 Preview working on VMware, because there are known problems with trying to get Windows 8 working virtually. It might be that this is only specific to the *Consumer* Preview, but it's worth looking around none-the-less.

Comment: works perfectly for me, same setup, using an iso

Comment: I wonder if it's as simple as it's just looking for a DVD rom due to some hard coded expectation, do you not have any DVD roms? If not install a virtual device tool like Daemon tools on the host OS...

Comment: Unless you are married to VMWare player, try virtualbox.  there is a great guide for the dev preview and consumer preview [HERE](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/btl/virtually-windows-8-how-to-set-up-the-consumer-preview-in-virtualbox/70330)

Comment: Which VMware version? Some tech blogs report that version 3.14 cannot be used to install and run W8... (but the articles are from last september and the things change fast...). Virtual Box is a good alternative imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMware says it could be a corrupted ISO file:
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1032711

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that in my case it was due to a corrupted download of the ISO file. The size of my file was not correct; and it gave the error mentioned in the question above, here on my VMware vSphere 5.0.

Use a download manager (e.g. Orbit Downloader) and compare the SHA-1 hash of the downloaded file with the SHA-1 value published at Microsofts download page. (Install HashTab, right-click the iso file and click the tab File Hashes) Or download from msdn.microsoft.com, as they use a buildin download manager which checks the integrity of the file.

Both Windows Server 8 Beta and Windows 8 Beta seems to run without any problems at my VMware vSphere 5.0 here.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an incomplete download by Google Chrome. So effectively a corrupt ISO as Peter said. Downloading the ISO again solved the issue. I used Safari and curl to have 2 horses in the race and they both worked just fine.

Compare the SHA1 hash provided by MS on the ISO download page to ensure you have the whole thing. The hash is `E91ED665B01A46F4344C36D9D88C8BF78E9A1B39`.